# Simple Injector - register collection

Tags: c#, mvvm, ioc-container, simple-injector

I use Simple Injector to create IoC container. I took pattern here:

[Page Navigation using MVVM in Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816264/page-navigation-using-mvvm-in-store-app/32272864#32272864)

As I asked in comment to above post, I would like to register collection of INavigationPage. I did it like that:

```
 private static void RegisterNavigationPages()
 {
        Container.RegisterCollection<INavigationPage>(new []
        {
            typeof(MainNavigationPage),
            typeof(SecondNavigationPage)
        });
 }
```

Inside the container I have ViewModels and NavigationService to:

```
Container.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
Container.Register<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
Container.Register<ISecondViewModel, SecondViewModel>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

This is way how I set DataContext of page:

```
DataContext = App.Container.GetInstance<IMainViewModel>();
```

Everything is OK but I want to use NavigationPages from that collection inside my ViewModel constructor. I can do it by index:

```
 public SecondViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IEnumerable<INavigationPage> navigationPageCollection)
 {
     NavigationService = navigationService;
     _navigationPage = (navigationPageCollection.ToList())[0];
     GoToMainPageCommand = new Command(GoToMainPageAction);
 }
```

but it isn't elegant solution because when I change order of NavigationPages I will have to change all indexes in whole application. Is it any solution when I will can recognize which NavigationPage I want to use in ViewModel constructor?

I can't do it by typeof, because that NavigationPage types are in UIProject and I can't have reference there from ViewModel project because of circular reference dependency.

Comment: So the `SecondViewModel` only ever needs to work with the `MainNavigationPage` or does it need more navigation pages by iterating them?

Comment: for now only that page, but in the future probably it will need more paging. There can be few buttons to few different pages. It is only skeleton of application. The target is about 10 pages with view models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the correctness of the `SecondViewModel` is completely dependent on the order and filling of the `navigationPageCollection`, which makes it really fragile. If your `SecondViewModel` needs a `MainNavigationPage`, that's what you should inject. Don't inject a collection; inject the page itself. That probably means that `MainNavigationPage` needs its own interface, such as `IMainNavigationPage`. That removes any ambiguity that you are having right now. But instead of having loads of one-to-one mapping non-generic interface (a violation of the [RAP principle](http://codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/?postid=934)), you might be better of defining a [few generic abstractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307033/how-to-use-wpf-controls-with-simple-injector-dependencies/32339958#32339958).

Comment: Actually the OP links to a SO question where the sample code provides a NavigationPage<T>. Moving the T from the there defined abstact class to the interface will solve the problem.

Comment: Not exacly, because I won't be able to inject it inside ViewModel, because I can't use Page type there so I can't do something like this in constructor parameters:

INavigationPage<MainPage> mainNavigationPage.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and have solved this issue before. Read my blog here [clean factory pattern](https://kusnaditjung.blogspot.co.uk/2017/12/clean-factory-design-pattern-with-ioc.html)

Basically what you need is to add a method or property to identify the user in the INavigationPage, and then also add the same identifier in the SecondViewModel. The SecondViewModel constructor just need to iterate through the IEnumerable and find the page that it needs.