# How do apply I Dependency Injection with MvvM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I've read Mark Seemann's book Dependency Injection in .NET. And I think I understand most of what he wrote.

The problem that I'm struggeling with is that I want to inject viewmodels into views.
I know this can be done by

```
public class CompositeRoot
{
    private IContainer container;
    public CompositeRoot()
    {
        //build the container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().As<IDatabaseContext>();
        builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().As<IMainViewModel>();
        container = builder.Build();

        //create a window and inject a viewmodel
        MainWindow mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.DataContext = container.Resolve<IMainViewModel>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

but this seems rather crude.

I was thinking about:

```
public class CompositeRoot
{
    private IContainer container;
    public CompositeRoot()
    {
        //build the container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().As<IDatabaseContext>();
        builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().As<IMainViewModel>();
        container = builder.Build();

    }

    public IMainViewModel MainVM
    {
         get { return container.resolve<IMainViewModel>(); }
    }
}
```

And then put in the xaml code

```
DataContext="{Binding MainVM, Source={StaticResource IoC}}"
```

(in the app.xaml I would have compositeroot be named a resource as IoC)

My question now is,  would this be good Dependency Injection, or would this still be the Service locator pattern  (which is an anti pattern so I don't want to use it)

if this is the anti pattern, what are my options?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307033/how-to-use-wpf-controls-with-simple-injector-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks perfectly valid to me. In fact this is the same approach that is used in the [MVVM light library](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Templates/CSharp/ProjectTemplates/VS2015/Mvvm.WPF451/ViewModelLocator.cs) (`CompositionRoot` is named `ViewModelLocator` instead). The important point is that the locator is just for use when binding views to view models, and should not be injected into view models (this would be the [service locator pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) you are trying to avoid).